# Android: developer console - Google Play

Tags: android

I have a problem with my DEMO application, which is for free. I can't see my app from US market - I think only from US market. Please check. There is only FULL app TrainBrain, but no FREE app. Does anybody know, where is the problem? And how can I check the availability in other countries?

This is a picture from developer console, where is the USA label crossed.
[PICTURE](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/55504275/1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/request.py?contact_type=publishing

Use this link and submit the ticket to google.

Google will give you proper response shortly and help sort out your issue.